# if statement, that calls a function and compares values to variables

Tags: bash, comparison

I use i3 and want to control the volume of my sink using the volume keys, that call pactl. Since pactl does not support a parameter for max volume, but is adviced to use with pipewire, the script should get the current volume and compare, if the next volume_increment step would result in a higher value than a certain max_volume. My confusion is now related to an if statement, with the combination of calculating the difference between the volume_increment and max_volume, and compare it to the outcome of the current_volume function. So the volume will be raised, until the certain value, where the increment would result in a higher volume then the maximum value

```
#!/bin/bash

volume_increment=$1
max_volume=$2

function get_volume() {
pactl get-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ | head -n1 | cut -d/ -f2 | tr -d ' %'
}
 
if (( get_volume >= $max_volume - $volume_increment )) ; then
    pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +$volume_increment%
else
    pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ $max_volume%
fi
```

I've googled a lot and tried several variations of brackets in the if statement. I've managed to get it to work at some intermediate step. But then I've read that (()) brackets are not universal for POSIX shells.

Now I'm very confused and can't separate these various aspects in my head.
Would someone be so kind to explain the logic of calling a function in a statement and compare it to a difference of variables? Preferably for universal POSIX usage, nut bash specific.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in arithmetic context, variables are implicitly expaned. Therefore, `((var))` uses `$var` automatically.

In your statement

```
(( get_volume >= $max_volume - $volume_increment ))
```

the $ is not needed - you could equally well have written `max_volume - volume_increment`, but you are refering to a variable `get_volume` and never set it. An unset variable is treated as zero, and therefore `get_volume` is always 0. Assuming that you can caluclate this value from the function `current_volume`, you could do a

```
get_volume=$(current_volume)
```

or run this function directly inside the arithmetic expression, i.e.

```
(( $(current_volume) >= $max_volume - $volume_increment ))
```

Of course, all this requires that you are restricting yourself to integer arithmetic in your script.

Comment: Thanks! I've realized a typo in my example script. Sorry, also reduced code to relevant parts.  So actually, I don't need to set a variable, that calls the function first, in order to use the value within my statement? Is there any best practise of using one of the methods?
A function in general can be called by using '''$(some_function)''', right? For a general POSIX purpuse, this comparison would lead to '''[[ $(get_volume) -le $max_volume - $volume_increment ]]'''?

Comment: I mean by using square brackets and -le/-ge/... The expression I've written im my last comment shure doesn't work :D

Comment: If you want to use double brackets, you'll have to evaluate the right-hand side as an [arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion): `[[ $(get_volume) -le $((max_volume - volume_increment)) ]]`. Certainly the arithmetic conditional is "cleaner"

Comment: _Is there any best practise of using one of the methods?_  Using a variable comes handy if you (maybe for debugging) also want to print the value to stdout. Apart from this, just use what you find bette readable.